# Evaluation of $\int_{0}^{\pi h} \ln\Big( \frac{y^{h}\sin{y}}{\prod_{j=1}^{h} (\pi j-y)}\Big)$

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Let $a=\pi h,$ $h$ positive integer and
$$J_h = \int_{0}^{\alpha} \ln\Bigg( \frac{y^{h}\sin{y}}{\prod_{j=1}^{h} (\pi j-y)}\Bigg) dy$$
The function 
$$f_h (y)= \frac{y^{h}\sin{y}}{\prod_{j=1}^{h} (\pi j-y)}$$
is positive in $(0,\alpha)-\{\pi,2\pi,...,(h-1)\pi\}.$
$\ln{f_h(y)}$ is not defined in $\{j\pi:j=0,1,...,h\}$ but can be continued extended for $j=1,2,...,h$ (the limits $\lim_{y\rightarrow \pi j}\ln(f_h(y))$ exist for $j=1,2,...,h$ but not for $j=0$). Although the integral exists, from Riemann - Lebesgue Theorem.

Some values are (computed with computer),
$$J_1=-\pi \ln{2}, J_2 = 0, J_3 = 6\pi \ln(3) - 7\pi\ln(2),$$
the code can be found https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=gmcnde.
If someone tries to "break" the $\ln$ , then the $\ln$ of the denominator is not well defined in some subintervals of $(0,\alpha)$. Although for $h=1$ the calculation of $J_1$ is easy. 
Any idea on how to compute it for $h>1?$

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for comments.*

*Apparently*
$$J_h=\pi \log \left(\frac{p_h}{q_h}\right)$$

Now, *observe* the prime factorizations for the $p_h$ and $q_h$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
h & \text{factors of } p_h & \text{factors of } q_h \\
 3 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 6
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 7
\end{array}
\right) \\
 4 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 16
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 6
\end{array}
\right) \\
 5 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 5 & 20
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 25 \\
 3 & 6
\end{array}
\right) \\
 6 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 4 \\
 3 & 24
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 5 & 10
\end{array}
\right) \\
 7 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 7 & 42
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 39 \\
 3 & 18 \\
 5 & 10
\end{array}
\right) \\
 8 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 128
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 18 \\
 5 & 10 \\
 7 & 14
\end{array}
\right) \\
 9 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 126
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 89 \\
 5 & 10 \\
 7 & 14
\end{array}
\right) \\
 10 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 5 & 80
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 54 \\
 7 & 14
\end{array}
\right) \\
 11 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 11 & 110
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 111 \\
 3 & 54 \\
 5 & 30 \\
 7 & 14
\end{array}
\right) \\
 12 & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 152 \\
 3 & 78
\end{array}
\right) & \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 5 & 30 \\
 7 & 14 \\
 11 & 22
\end{array}
\right)
\end{array}
\right)$$

May be, this could give you some ideas.